# How to decrypt session-token (Next-auth JWT token)

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I am controlling user authentification in my next app with `next-auth` library

I am using the `credentials provider`. First I call the login endpoint which returns the user informations then I take the access token and put it inside the token given by `next-auth callback`.

this is my code in `[...nextauth].js`

```js
const authOptions = {
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      type: "credentials",
      credentials: {},
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        const { email, password } = credentials;
        const result = await axios.post(
          `http://127.0.0.1:5000/user/login`,
          {
            email,
            password,
          },
          {
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            withCredentials: true,
          }
        );
        return {
          accessToken: result.data.accessToken,
        };
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ user, token }) {
    if (user?.accessToken) {
    token.value = user.accessToken;
      }
    console.log(token); //<-- output below
    return token;
    },
  },
};
```

output :

```
{
  value: 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjYzOTZiMTlhYTczMmUzMzYwMjU2ZjBlMiIsImlhdCI6MTY3NTAyMzEwNSwiZXhwIjoxNjc1MTA5NTA1fQ.5kdPmeLCpwbJBjtzKMhe5QMNEx75ThiDKm75PN0vjoc',
  iat: 1675023106,
  exp: 1675109506,
  jti: 'd9108700-1b5f-4bd3-8d31-0c36f38d9fcb'
}
```

Now in `getServerSideProps` I can get it from the request because it is sent in Cookie

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  console.log(context.req.cookies["next-auth.session-token"]); // <-- output in Blockquote
  return {
   // does not matter
  };
}
```

I get this :

> eyJhbGciOiJkaXIiLCJlbmMiOiJBMjU2R0NNIn0..6ryJ60GPcDLq9aWG.4oWlJbecyWUnbZYJiv6z0eAuFmRFSfEn4fQSlh1FTjlPiiDGZASA4UwqXNEHRpRMG6HRPRDcsUUCHBBzaV8JwCEetgSYJcSrZ5CK_AhyvFKUlKY-TpHSNDnmCI8ZS4y2nV_Xl0NqvMU3vA-D8gXtT5UcOrJLlN5dMe7S9xZo8vhr-gpohcEhKOefUgDjTmMYmBf190OLl0TY599FkJwpoeSFozAwavwbOZGQOxYVbsj3KTibsfE37juyqnDaiV_t59bWroGjz2d5kHLxfkpQB0IKYRnAH8sXbG7dDZUVLT1UQUN_FrjYpkFrQgxC7MmWZtCccQs-FsBXY7EbiYmJKIddpOeN1Q.1kas8bGE_O7IkEDiilxiZw

Now I want to decrypt this token to get its proprety value (which is the `accessToken`) and use it.

is it possible to decrypt it with javascript ? Thank you for your attention !

Comment: Why don't you just use the getSession and getToken functions build in?

https://next-auth.js.org/v3/tutorials/securing-pages-and-api-routes#using-getsession

Comment: I don't want to store the accessToen in the session

Comment: Have you tried the getToken function?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've parsed `["next-auth.session-token"]` from `req.cookies`. Then now. You could decrypt the token by using `decode` method from `next-auth/jwt` to get JSON payload.

```js
import { decode } from 'next-auth/jwt';
```

Here's an example.

```js
import { decode } from 'next-auth/jwt';

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const sessionToken = context.req.cookies['next-auth.session-token'];

  const decoded = await decode({
    token: sessionToken,
    secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
  });

  // decoded JSON will be like :
  /**
   * {
   *  name: 'John Doe',
   *  email: '...',
   *  image: '...'
   * }
   */
}
```

Comment: In v5 `next-auth/jwt` is deprecated. Is there another way?

Answer (score 3):

There is a built-in helper method [getToken()](https://next-auth.js.org/configuration/options#jwt-helper) for doing that :

> For convenience, this helper function is also able to read and decode tokens passed from the Authorization: 'Bearer token' HTTP header.

```js
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";
```

```js
const secret = 'MY_SECRET';

export default async function handler(req, res) { 
  const token = await getToken({ req, secret })
  console.log("JSON Web Token", token)
  res.end()
}
```

> If using `NEXTAUTH_SECRET` env variable, we detect it, and you won't actually need to `secret`

```js
export default async function handler(req, res) { 
  const token = await getToken({ req })
  console.log("JSON Web Token", token)
  res.end()
}
```

Comment: How to use this?

Comment: Please provide a complete working example

Comment: This is already a complete working example

Comment: Thanks, this should be used instead of manually specifying the name and decode, as the token name can change once deployed (HTTPS).

Comment: @Alex yeah this is the official way