# How to decode next-auth jwt token to get access_token for use in RTK query

Tags: javascript, next.js, next-auth, rtk-query

I am making use of next-auth.js for authentication and I have successfully implemented the credentials sign in method. After successful authentication, the jwt is stored in the cookie.

Is there a way to retrieve this cookie, decode it and take out the `access_token` I stored in it for use in an external api call using RTK query?
I don't want to make this token available in the session

Here is my next-auth.js configuration file

```
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";

export default NextAuth({
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      type: "credentials",
      credentials: {},
      authorize: async (user) => {
        return user;
      },
    }),
  ],
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
  callbacks: {
    jwt: async ({ token, user }) => {
      if (user) {
        token.access_token = user.token;
        token.id = user.id;
      }

      return token;
    },
    session: async ({ session, token }) => {
      if (token) {
        session.id = token.id;
      }
      return session;
    },
  },
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Next-auth how to decrypt session-token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74984195/next-auth-how-to-decrypt-session-token)